# copying multiple data to a single cell in visual basic excel

Tags: excel, vba

i revised my question for clarification.
i really don't know the basic code for this visual basic in excel but i want it actually to look like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGbkK.jpg

In the example picture, for instance if I click a button, column 'I' should store the values, separated by a dot, from each cell of columns 'C','D','F'. the code should be applicable as long as there's a value in columns C,D,F so it doesn't mean it is always on row 6. thank you for the help!

Comment: Try the `Concatenate` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 7).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(C3,""."",D3,""."",E3)"
```

Comment: thank you very much! my problem now is what if i have now multiple values or until there's an empty cell for column C3, D3, and E3?

Comment: What if you do have multiple values or blank cells? That's not in the scope of your question.

Comment: what you want to archive? .2.3 or 2.3? .2.3 works

Comment: oh sorry i didn't think about that thank you for pointing it out. to be safe there could be blank cells. but more likely this would look like this. http://i.imgur.com/GueY2F1.jpg?1 it is the same concept as above, column I should store the values from columns C,D,F. also it is not limited to row 6 in my example. the code should be applicable as long as there's a value in columns C,D,F thank you for your help i'm kinda new to visual basic in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Formula for cell G3

```
 =C3 & "." & D3 & "." & E3
```